# Duda sobre el uso de fadeto() en evento change en un select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Intento que al poner en mi lista a "x" opacidad se cambie la una lista de elementos, el código de JS lo tengo separado a un archivo externo, no sé si no está bien la función en JS o si no sé como inicializarla.

Código HTML

```
<select name="opacidad" id="porcentaje">
                                <option value="1" selected="1">100%</option>
                                <option value="0.8">80%</option>
                                <option value="0.5">50%</option>
                                <option value="0.2">20%</option>
                                <option value="0">0%</option>

                            </select>

<ul id="lista">
                <li id="e1"><h4>Elemento 1</h4></li>
                <li id="e2"><h4>Elemento 2</h4></li>
                <li id="e3"><h4>Elemento 3</h4></li>
            </ul>
```

Código Js

```
$('#porcentaje').change(function(e){
var opacidad_des = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value;
$("h4").fadeto(500, opacidad_des);                      
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Estaba todo bien, no entiendo por qué no me iba al principio, volví a probrarlo poniendo como etiqueta $('#lista') y me funcionó. **Cambié de IIS a Apache24** porque me estaba dando unos problemas con js y jquery, supongo que sería eso.